# How do i do the following task with quickbase?

Tags: quickbase

How do i know the users who added the record in quickbase table or who have the permission to add ,Edit or delete the record or how can i check the flow of adding a data into quickbase tables ?

Answer (score 2):

When you create a table in quickbase, it defaults to creating a field that display which user account has inserted the record.  The default names are **Record Owner** and **Last Modified By**.

**Record Owner** is for the user who initially created the record.

**Last Modified By** is for the user account that last modified the record.

**Date Created** will tell you when it was created and **Date modified** will tell you when it was last modified.  These fields are not default in reports.  I would make a custom report that only the administrators can see to follow the tracking of the flow of records adding and editing.

The help file at this link [QuickBase Help for User Control](http://www.quickbase.com/help/default.html#Who_uses_QuickBase_.html) will help you understand how to manage your user accounts and also know who has access to what for which application.

Hope this helps.